# Need Material recommendation for area around shower

Tags: bathroom, shower

I'm looking for a Material recommendation for above my shower.

I live in a very old house that's been renovated several times.  In our main bathroom, there is an 8-inch build out away from the main wall were plumbing for the shower is, and a 3-inch one on the window side.  I'm assuming this is because the room is an odd size, and the old owners were accommodating a prefab shower-tub fixture.  As you can see from the picture, there's also Wainscotting, moulding, a faucet, and curtain rod to contend with.  Also this about 4-inches away from the toilet, which is just below the picture.  This section runs floor to ceiling. Material is freshly primed drywall, though you can see some damaged sections in the picture where there is some exposed metal corner material.

I'm looking for a "Tile-esq" material to potentially cover that entire section (above the shower on 3 sides as well as the long sections on either side).  However I'm not ~super~ handy.  I think tiling with "real" tiles for an area that big and oddly shaped is above my skill.

I'm imagining a faux-tile made out of some sort of vinyl or acrylic or polymer-something.   Here is my checklist of desires:

- Waterproof, shower-proof, easy to wipe clean
- Will hold up in long a narrow strip, and on both convex and concave corners.
- Easy to Cut and shape (ideally with shears or utility knife)
- Relatively easy to install (easier than tiles ideally)

Mostly looking for recommendations on how to find what I'm looking for (so either a company or a keyword or a link).  I went down to the local Home Depot and they lots and lots of tiles, but I couldn't find anything like what I was imagining. Also if this is a "bad idea", please let me know - I have no problem just painting that area.[image]

Comment: Is there a reason a mold-resistant paint won't do?

Comment: It's in between two different splash-zones (the shower and the toilet).  The bottom section is really rough.  That's the real reason I was considering non-paint options.  Something that would be more resistant to being wet, and easy to just wipe clean.

Comment: If you have splash from the toilet you're in real bad shape...